# Excel formula to compute value

Tags: excel-2007

Trying to write a formula to compute value of cells and if greater than or equal to 4000 then insert 4000. If less than 4000 then insert computed value of cells. This is what I have so far.

```
=if(M4+H10-sum(M5:M9)>=4000,"4000","M4+H10-sum(M5:M9)")
```

When I add values to cells M5 thru M9 I get an error value . So I may not be able to add a formula as the false condition of the "if" function.

Answer (score 1):

Just removing "" in false condition will help.

```
=IF(M4+H10-sum(M5:M9)>=4000,"4000",M4+H10-sum(M5:M9))
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use the following formula.

```
=MIN(M4+H10-SUM(M5:M9),4000)
```

Note that in the previous solution, I believe the quotes around 4000 will cause it to be treated like text.

Answer (score 0):

OK it appears that you have to lose the quotation marks in order for the formula to be calculated. The quotation marks are used to display text only. Thanks to all that replied
Glenn